# "Sono cinque giorni che sono sveglio." Vs. "Sono rimasto sveglio per cinque giorni."

Tags: difference

a) Sono cinque giorni che sono sveglio.

b) Sono rimasto sveglio per cinque giorni.

C'è qualcuno che coglie una differenza di enfasi fra a) e b)?

Answer (score 4):

Le due frasi sono molto simili. Se proprio si vuole cercare una differenza, direi che la prima pone più l'accento sul momento in cui ho iniziato a stare sveglio (5 giorni fa) mentre la seconda più sulla durata senza dare indicazioni su quando questa cosa è iniziata (i 5 giorni di veglia potrebbero esserci stati il mese scorso e non ora).

Comment: Sono d'accordo, anche se nessuna delle due mi sembra molto idiomatica; in più nella prima delle due c'è la ripetizione di “sono” che è un po' cacofonica. Io direi qualcosa come «Sono cinque giorni che non dormo» (lievissimamente più enfatico) oppure «Non dormo da cinque giorni».

Answer (score 1):

a) implica che lo stare sveglio continua ancora ora e forse continuerà nel futuro, il periodo non si è concluso;

b) indica  che sono stato sveglio nel passato, compreso il caso che il passato si sia concluso nel momento appena passato; il periodo si è comunque concluso.